# With jQuery, can I make it so the submit button won't "work" unless the required fields are filled out

Tags: php, jquery

I want the user to be able to click submit, but if the correct fields aren't filled out it will not go through and errors will appear. Is this possible? I know how to do the errors part, but the blocking submit part is annoying.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: As to your actual question: yes, of course you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the submit event on the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#yourFormIdHere").submit(function(e) {
         // process fields
         if (thereWereErrors) {
             e.preventDefault();
         }
     });
});
```

If you call the [`event.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in an event handler it stops the default action for that event from happening, where in the case of the submit event the default is of course to submit the form...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want: (I reckon) **working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8YsAx/

Good link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

API: `validate` http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerForm").validate();
  });​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post/get" action"url" onsubmit="return Validation();">
```

The onsubmit is called when the submit is clicked.  The Validation function should return true for continue and false if you want to prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: -1 for recommending an inline JavaScript solution when jQuery is available to make it totally avoidable.

Comment: You're right, but I don't reference anywhere JQuery.  Not everyone uses JQuery.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the title of the question, _"**With jQuery**, can I make it so...?"_

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking how to do it (instead of what you actually ask which is "is this possible"), then you can just do something like this in your jquery code.  This is a way to do it if you're submitting multiple forms.

```
if($(your_field_here).html() === '') {
  error = 1;
  error_field .= "<br />your_field_here is not filled out!";
}
if($(your_second_field_here).html() === '') {
  error = 1;
  error_field .= "<br />your_field_here is not filled out!";
}

if(error === 1){
  $(your_error_field).html(error_field);
} else {
  // do your ajax / w.e call here
}
```

edit: this is something that I've personally always done.  If there is an easier method, please let me know via comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a submit-Eventlistener to the Form:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    // return true (proceed submit) | false (stop submit)     
    // In case the form is not valid you can render your errorMessages first    
});
```